# Adding User to Site group fails for form based authentication using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, 2016, forms-authentication, user

When attempting to add a user using PowerShell to a SP2016, which has Form Base Authentication active, New-SPUser fails with user not found.

The following works for Domain users.

```
$web = Get-SpWeb $SiteCollectionURL
$claim = New-SPClaimsPrincipal -EncodedClaim 'i:0#.w|domain\username'
$SPUserClaim = New-SPUser -UserAlias $Claim.ToEncodedString() -Web $Web.Url 
$web.SiteGroups['TestSiteWithGroups Members'].AddUser($SPUserClaim)
```

But the following fails when attempting the same for a custom **role** provider.

```
$claim = New-SPClaimsPrincipal -EncodedClaim 'c:0-.f|aimrolemanager|client administrator - clientname'
$SPUserClaim = New-SPUser -UserAlias $Claim.ToEncodedString() -Web $Web.Url -Group 'TestSiteWithGroups Members'
```

Fails with

> New-SPUser : The specified user c:0-.f|customrolemanager|client administrator - clientname could not be found.

I can add the user "client administrator - clientname" via people picker without issue.